Replacement in $M[G]$.
In the answer given in here Replacement in M[G], how do we know that $S = R(a)^M \cap M^{\mathbb{P}}$ is in $M$? By the fact that we can define it in $M$? I suppose $M$ has a way to name $M^{\mathbb{P}}$ itself? Am I correct that generally, $M^{\mathbb{P}}$ is not an element of $M$ (although it is by definition a subset, AFAICT)?
And why does being able to define $S$ imply that it is an element of $M$? I suppose by the fact that we know that $M$ satisfies comprehension, so that we can form $\{x \in R(a)^M: (x \ \text{is a} \ \mathbb{P}\text{-}\text{name})^M\}$?
